# C++ : Why this window title gets truncated?

Tags: c++, winapi

Visual C++ 2012 RC, Win7

Chinese simplified

Project Properties > use multi byte character set

When I run this program, the window's title shows a single letter "S", not a whole word "Sample".

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SubSystem:Windows")

#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PSTR, int) {
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };

    wc.style            = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground    = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    wc.lpszClassName    = L"MyWindowClass";

    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        if (uMsg - WM_DESTROY)
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        else {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return HRESULT();
        }
    };

    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    CreateWindowExW(0, L"MyWindowClass", L"Sample",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, SW_SHOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    for (MSG msg; GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0); DispatchMessage(&msg));
}
```

If I use Unicode (Project Properties), keep source code unchanged, window title shows "Sample", looks correct.

If I use multi byte, in source code I use WNDCLASS = { ..., "MyWindowClass" } and RegisterClassA, keep CreateWindowExW unchanged, window title shows word "Sample", looks correct.

If I use multi byte, in source code I use CreateWindowExA("MyWindowClass", "Sample"), keep WNDCLASSW and RegisterClassW unchanged, window title shows letter "S".

What makes it show a single "S", am I doing something wrong?

**Append**

If I keep all unchanged, that is, use multi byte, use code shown above, window title shows letter "S".

(If you run this program and see "Sample" on window title, rather than "S", then it's more likely a specific problem on chs version of vc++ 2012 (or OS)).

Comment: Why have you posted the code for the version that works correctly? The version that doesn't work would be much more useful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: This looks strange. The RegisterClass version used determines if it is a Unicode window (`IsWindowUnicode()`) or not. Windows does two way translation Unicode <-> ANSI, so you should be able to mix Unicode and ANSI function calls. But: why would you want to do this? Why not just use one of them, preferrably the ones without A and W at the end, so that the windows header files map to the version as set in the project properties (e.g. `RegisterClass` - without A or W, mapping to `RegisterClassA` or `RegisterClassW` automatically)?

Comment: @Joe Gauterin If code posted above is correct, correctly shows "Sample" in window title, then maybe it's a bug on VC++ 2012  RC chs. Code posted above shows a single "S" on my system :D

Comment: @user1345484: You question states that the problem occurs only when you use `CreateWindowExA`, but the code you posted uses `CreateWindowExW`.

Comment: @Joe Gauterin Sorry for misleading! I'll edit the post to make it more clear. By the way, when you run the code shown above, your window title shows a word "Sample" or a letter "S"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using `DefWindowProc` instead of `DefWindowProcW`. Changing that will fix the code.

Ideally you should change your project settings to use Unicode, not multi-byte character set. This will simplify everything and you can use the macros like `CreateWindowEx` and `RegisterClassEx` instead of explicitly using the Unicode / ANSI versions as you are.

As others have said, this is a mismatch between character sets.

You should ideally match character sets between all your API calls that interact with each other. So if you use `CreateWindowExW` you should also use `RegisterClassExW`, `DefWindowProcW`, `DispatchMessageW`...

Comment: This clearly is best practice. But where did you find a definition that says you can't mix RegisterClassW and CreateWindowA? The MSDN documentation for `IsWindowUnicode` says you can mix Unicode and ANSI (windows and messages). Unfortunately they do not say something about CreateWindowExA/W and RegisterClassA/W.

Comment: @WernerHenze: You're right that it is not imperative. In fact I was wrong that it was a mismatch between `CreateWindowEx` and `RegisterClassEx`. It was actually a mismatch between `RegisterClassEx` and `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: @tenfour: DefWindowProcW, exactly! Problem solved, Thanks! When use RegisterClassW/CreateWindowExW, we must call DefWindowProcW. To Werner Henze: "This clearly is best practice. But where did you find a definition that says you can't mix RegisterClassW and CreateWindowA?" Agreed :D

Comment: I had the same problem with C# while importing WinApi and creating windows. Seems all functions dealing with `HWND` or just those function passing `WPARAM` or `LPARAM` must use the same char set. Because `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` can contain structs and / or strings which make the problem arise.

Comment: @tenfour You're a freakin' genius! DefWindowProc was the problem (cost me half a day). Who'da thought? BTW it is not always practical to just turn on the _UNICODE switch at the project level. When converting a large legacy codebase, it is sometimes preferable to gradually transition to Unicode by selectively converting sub-sections.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very nice one, learned something new!

You need to change

```
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

to

```
if(IsWindowUnicode(hWnd))  
  return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);  
else  
  return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

Or even better: stick to one character encoding. At best just use `RegisterClass`, `CreateWindowEx` and so on and let the compiler take the right Unicode or ANSI function.

Comment: Thanks! In practice, I will stick to these macor Api and TEXT(). As for fun, I'd like to look something strange. :D

Answer (score 2):

CreateWindowExA interprets the string as 8 bit characters. The second 8 bits of L"Sample" is zero, because its first character is 0x0053 - the L means use wide characters. So the function interprets that as a 1 character null terminated string.

Comment: Also, don't use CreateWindowExA or CreateWindowExW, just use CreateWindowEx and let the preprocessor work out which one you should be using according to your character set settings. Same for all the other Win32 functions.

Comment: The original poster said that in case he calls `CreateWindowExA("MyWindowClass", "Sample")` the window title is not correct. He is not writing `L"Sample"` there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [msdn page for `RegisterClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) hints at the reason for the failure here, in the remarks section it mentions how that if you use either wide character or ansi support, then it will pass internal text paramaters/message in this format (wide char/ansi).  Quite possibly that's what's happening with the window title, even though we're saying use `CreateWindowExA`, this doesn't work as internally the Windows SDK has encoded that string as a wide character string, and the `CreateWinowExA` tries to output as if it was an Ansi string.

In short don't go mixing the W and A methods, unless you've a good reason for doing so, and let windows headers take care of it for you, if you want wide char support define your UNICODE macro.

Answer (score 0):

In your last case your L"Sample" still remains Unicode, isn't it? You can use _T() macro, which automatically adds or removes L prefix depending on Unuicode setting of the project.

And Unicode L"Sample", as @Pete have already said, is "S\0..." in ascii, that's why only one symbol is printed.

Comment: You use `_T()` with the `CreateWindowEx` macro. Here he is explicitly using `CreateWindowExW` so this is not relevant.

Comment: Please read my post again, I am speaking about author's last case only (where he has got problems). He is using CreateWindowExA there.

Comment: The original poster said that in case he calls CreateWindowExA("MyWindowClass", "Sample") the window title is not correct. He is not writing L"Sample" there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad I found this.  I was looking all over for an answer, and it seems rather difficult to find correctly with Google etc.  I did find similar problems reported for specific programs, always blaming "some plug in".

It is maddening because the problem with the WndProc is nowhere near the call to CreateWindowEx nor RegisterClassEx!

BTW, I use -W suffixes explicitly, because I want to make one DLL that works for programs built either way, or overcome the non-Unicode settings of the program I'm adding to.